# Is there a pattern for a chain of asynchronous calls, followed by a cleanup?

Tags: design, design-patterns, asynchronous-programming

I have two asynchronous tasks that need to get completed - say they're "make a pie" (`make`) and "bake a pie" (`bake`). I also need to cleanup after everything's done - "clean the kitchen" (`cleanup`). `bake` depends on `make`, and I want to `cleanup` when things are done. However, there are a few complications:

- If some nice person has already `made` the pie, all I have to do is `bake`.
- If a problem happens during `make` - maybe I get tired of this whole pie business - I need to `cleanup`.
- If a problem happens during `bake` - the oven explodes - I also need to `cleanup`.

My first pass looks like something like this:

```
func pieTime()
    if !pie.isMade()
        make()
    else if !pie.isBaked()
        bake()
    else
        cleanup(null)

func make()
    makeThePie(completion: {
        if pie.hasError()
            cleanup(error)
        else
            bake()
    })

func bake()
    bakeThePie(completion: {
        if pie.hasError()
            cleanup(error)
        else
            cleanup(null)
    })

func cleanup(error)
    if error != null
        shout("what the ***: %s", error.string())
    destroy(pie)
```

This isn't too bad, but my main problem with this approach is that there is no single exit point from the flow. `cleanup` gets called from a bunch of places. As the error handling gets more complicated, and you add more asynchronous calls to the chain, there are more and more exit points from the flow to keep track of. If I miss calling `cleanup` at any of them, the result is an unusable kitchen.

Basically, I'm looking for something like a do/catch/finally for asynchronous calls. The only thing I could come up with is a queue - queue up only the tasks you need and queue cleanup at the end - but it seems a bit too heavyweight for just two tasks, such as this instance. Is there a well-established pattern for this problem?

Comment: Yes, do-catch-finally is exactly the pattern you are looking for. If you could be a bit more specific about the language you are implementing this in, we can tell how to apply the pattern also to asynchronous functions.

Comment: I was hoping for a language-agnostic answer, but if it is important, I am working in objective-c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a **promise chain** like the idiomatic [`q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) one, roughly:

```
doSomethingThatReturnsAPromise
    .then(function (result, error) {
        if (error) {
            [the previous command failed in some way; handle it or throw.]
        }
    })
    .then([same again])
    […]
    .finally(function() {
        [global cleanup]
    })
```

The main difference from a tree of calls is that it's very intuitive to follow - there's no question of what the entry point is, there's no question of the sequence of the steps, and the cleanup happens unconditionally once the sequence is done.

Comment: Seems same as OP's first approach

Comment: I guess the difference is the `finally` - I didn't know promises supported this. I'm actually in Objective-C, but there is apparently a [library for this](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) which looks pretty much like what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

- implement functions `bake` and `make` without any calls to `cleanUp` (but coherent error signaling like a specific exception)
- implement a functional wrapper (a "decorator") which takes an arbitrary function as parameter, runs it asynchronously, catches any error exception and calls `cleanup` accordingly?

Then the place in code where `bake` and `make` (and other equivalent tasks) are started just have to use the wrapper to run the tasks. The final `cleanup(null)` should not be called by `bake` directly as well, but by the caller (for example, when he gets the event for all tasks having completed without any error).

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with because it was less invasive. However, I feel that the selected answer is the one I would implement if given no constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanup method can serve as a decorator for the make and bake command chain.  In this case, the decorator serves the purpose of cleaning up.  As the command chain executes, any error will move up the chain until the cleanup catches and cleans.

There is no reason to add in async as part of this chain since baking depends on making and error handling also depends on the result of making and possibly baking.  If you wanted to run the entire chain async (making and baking several pies at once,  then at the very top I would make an async callout and then look at the task result of the entire call chain as opposed to individual call outs.

Here's the chain (In C#):

```
var command = new PieCleanup(new MakePie(new BakePie()));
//You could run this async if many pies to make and bake
command.Execute(new Pie());
```

The Cleanup Decorator:

```
    public class PieCleanup : ICommand<Pie>
    {
        private readonly ICommand<Pie> _command;

        public PieCleanup(ICommand<Pie> command)
        {
            _command = command;
        }

        public void Execute(Pie pie)
        {
            try
            {
                _command.Execute(pie);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //TODO:  Cleanup
            }
        }
    }
```

Make Pie:

```
 public class MakePie : ICommand<Pie>
    {
        private readonly ICommand<Pie> _command;

        public MakePie(ICommand<Pie> command)
        {
            _command = command;
        }

        public void Execute(Pie pie)
        {
            //TODO: Make Pie
            //Now Run the next command (bake)
            _command.Execute(pie);
        }
    }
```

Bake Pie:

```
 public class BakePie : ICommand<Pie>
    {
        public void Execute(Pie pie)
        {
            //TODO: Bake Pie
        }
    }
```